# Insert duplicating first insert, but not any others

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I have a PHP script that looks like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $value = $this->input->post($key);
      $ingredientQTY = $this->input->post('ingredientQTY');
      $measurements = $this->input->post('measurements');
      $ingredientNAME = $this->input->post('ingredientNAME');
      $ingredientsROW[] = array($ingredientQTY, $measurements, $ingredientNAME);
    
      for ($i = 0, $count = count($ingredientQTY); $i < $count; $i++) {
            $rows[] = array(
                'ingredientamount'         => $ingredientQTY[$i],
                'ingredientType' =>  $measurements[$i],
                'ingredientname'        => $ingredientNAME[$i],
                'recipe_id' => $recipe_id,
                'order' => $i + 1,
                'user_id' => $user_id
            );
            $sql = "INSERT `ingredients` (`ingredientamount`,`ingredientType`,`ingredientname`, `recipe_id`, `order`, `user_id`) VALUES ";
            $coma = '';
            foreach ($rows as $oneRow) {
                $sql .= $coma."('".implode("','",$oneRow)."')";
                $coma = ', ';
            }
            $this->db->query($sql);
      }
      break;
    }
```

which inserts into a database called ingredients. My form looks like this:

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<span>
  <input type="text" class='pluralizer small' name="ingredientQTY[]" placeholder='QTY'/>
  <select name='measurements[]'>
    <option value='' name='' checked='checked' data-single="--" data-other="--">--</option>
    <?foreach ($measurements as $m):?>
        <option value='<?=$m->measurement;?>' data-single="<?=$m->measurement;?>" data-other="<?=$m->measurementPlural;?>">
          </option>
    <?endforeach;?>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="ingredientNAME[]" class="ingredient" placeholder='Ingredient'/>
  <a class='float-right delete-button deleteThis' style='margin:10px 2px;' href='#'><img src='<? echo base_url()."public/img/delete.png";?>' height='11' width='11' /></a>
</span>
```

For some reason, when I insert (which works fine, other than the issue I'm going to mention) the first row I insert gets duplicated in the mysql table `ingredients`, but all the subsequent rows are just inserted once. Why the heck does it do that?

Thanks for all help! If you need any more details, just ask!

Comment: did you check what's coming over from the form? e.g. `var_dump($_POST)`. make sure nothing's duped there. Then echo out your query statements at each stage, see you if you get any dupe outputs. And note that you're wide-open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! I var_dump(ed) and its not duplicated there. I'm using the CodeIgniter input class, which sanitizes the inputs, right?. Is there more I need to do for SQL Injection?

Comment: @MarcB Somewhere in the above code it must be looping the query statements because I have one where everything is correct, and another that just inserts the first row again, but I can't figure out where it does that in my above code?

Comment: No idea. Though the fact that you're doing `foreach(... => $value) { $value = ...` seems kind of hinky to me. if you want just the array keys, you can do `foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `$this->db->query($sql);` outside of your for-loop and reset `$rows` to be an empty array on each iteration of the foreach-loop.

try this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = $this->input->post($key);
  $ingredientQTY = $this->input->post('ingredientQTY');
  $measurements = $this->input->post('measurements');
  $ingredientNAME = $this->input->post('ingredientNAME');
  $ingredientsROW[] = array($ingredientQTY, $measurements, $ingredientNAME);
  $rows = array();
  for ($i = 0, $count = count($ingredientQTY); $i < $count; $i++) {
        $rows[] = array(
            'ingredientamount'         => $ingredientQTY[$i],
            'ingredientType' =>  $measurements[$i],
            'ingredientname'        => $ingredientNAME[$i],
            'recipe_id' => $recipe_id,
            'order' => $i + 1,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );
        $sql = "INSERT `ingredients` (`ingredientamount`,`ingredientType`,`ingredientname`, `recipe_id`, `order`, `user_id`) VALUES ";
        $coma = '';
        foreach ($rows as $oneRow) {
            $sql .= $coma."('".implode("','",$oneRow)."')";
            $coma = ', ';
        }
  }
  $this->db->query($sql);
  break;
}
```